# NodeJs WinstonJS very weird start

Tags: node.js, winston

I just started using winstonJS for NodeJS app logging.

My code goes like this :

```
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    levels: { error: 0, warn: 1, info: 2, debug: 3, trace: 4 },
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)()
    ]
});

logger.log('error', 'log0');
logger.log('warn', 'log1');
logger.log('info', 'log2');
logger.log('debug', 'log3');
logger.log('trace', 'log4');
```

and the **ONLY** logs that I get in my console are :

```
info: log2
trace: log4
debug: log3
```

Note the wrong order as well.

Am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider 2 things:

1. Console transport is created always with default level "info" unless you specify a different level
2. when you specify a level for a transport, the logger will print all the message with level >= than the specified level

Also consider that the default logging levels for winston are: `silly=0, debug=1, verbose=2, info=3, warn=4, error=5`

Analyzing your code I can see you defined a new "info" level, with value of 2: this means the console log will print only messages with levels >= 2, and in your example these levels are exactly info, debug and trace (I guess you define your levels in the wrong order).
If you change your code like this, you will see all the message printed:

```
transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({level: 'error'})
]
```

About the wrong output order I can't reproduce it, my output is always

```
info: log2
debug: log3
trace: log4
```

PS: if you define levels like this `error: 0, warn: 1, infoz: 2, debug: 3, trace: 4` with anything different replacing `info`, the logger will print nothing at all because the default console transport level will remain `info`. You can discover your transport level with a simple

```
console.log(logger.transports.console.level);
```